# How publish changes to OData feed from Excel

Tags: excel, odata, wcf-data-services, powerquery

I've created an `IUpdateable` ODATA feed using WCF which I can connect to using Excel 2010 Power Query. Excel is able to retrieve data but I cannot find a 'publish' button or anyway to tell Excel to push updates back to the server.

Does Excel / Power Query support ODATA CRUD functions out of the box?

Is there another tool I could use to update data without writting code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Power Query supports reading from data sources, but we don't support Create/Update/Delete.

I agree with you--it would be awesome to publish data from Excel without having to write any code!

If you think this is something Power Query should have, I'd go to https://ideas.powerbi.com and vote up the feature (you might be the first with the idea).

---

**Edit(2019):** Looks like several people have upvoted this one: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/12251397-q-a-can-you-perform-crud-operations-with-powerquer

Comment: Excel (2013 and onwards) is able to retrieve data from OData feeds using the Data tab->Other data sources->Odata feed without Power Query but it does not support data updates back to the data source. You'll have to write code or use a plugin that is OData compliant for that.

Data updates back in the data source are something a bit out of what Excel is intended for (mostly retrieval of data from a variety of data sources and manipulation of that data on Excel worksheets) so updating the data in the data source requires customization (code/plugins).

Comment: @FunkSoulBrother `Data tab->Other data sources->Odata feed` is power query. Its just a wizard to let you make it without writing power query language. Make one that way and go to advanced editor.